# Gradle: exclude (not skip) a task when it's up to date

Tags: gradle

I'm looking for a way to avoid running dependencies of a task that is up to date (while still running any tasks that are dependencies of other, not up-to-date tasks).

Take the following structure:

```
task stopService {}
task startService {}
task doUpdateA { // change something about the service }
task doUpdateB { // change something else about the service }

task updateA {
    inputs.files <some inputs>
    output.upToDateWhen { true }
    // i.e. run whenever inputs changed from previous run

    dependsOn stopService
    dependsOn doUpdateA
    dependsOn startService

    // ensure the service is stopped while it's being modified
    doUpdateA.mustRunAfter stopService
    startService.mustRunAfter doUpdateA
}


task updateB {
    inputs.files <some inputs>
    output.upToDateWhen { true }
    // i.e. run whenever inputs changed from previous run

    dependsOn stopService
    dependsOn doUpdateB
    dependsOn startService

    // ensure the service is stopped while it's being modified
    doUpdateB.mustRunAfter stopService
    startService.mustRunAfter doUpdateB
}

task updateAll {
    dependsOn updateA
    dependsOn updateB
}
```

The desired execution flow for `./gradlew updateAll`:

- If both updateA and updateB are up to date, do nothing
- If one of them is not up to date, `stopService -> doUpdateX -> startService`
- If both of them are not up to date, `stopService -> doUpdateA -> doUpdateB -> startService` (or B before A).

Is this possible, perhaps by hooking into the task execution graph and manually running upToDate on all tasks, then excluding them if they are up to date? Assume no task makes another task out of date.

---- Half-solutions:

If I ignore the third requirement, this can be somewhat solved by doing:
    task updateB {
        inputs.files 
        output.upToDateWhen { true }
        // i.e. run whenever inputs changed from previous run

```
    doLast {
        stopService.execute()
        doUpdateB.execute()
        startService.execute()
    }
}
```

but that's suboptimal for a couple reasons - dependencies / finalisers (i think?) of stop/startService won't be ran, each update will cause a separate stop/start (making the build much longer), etc.

If you ignore requirement 1, something like:

```
task updateAll {
    inputs.files <some inputs>
    output.upToDateWhen { true }
    // i.e. run whenever inputs changed from previous run

    dependsOn stopService
    dependsOn doUpdateA
    dependsOn doUpdateB
    dependsOn startService

    doUpdateB.mustRunAfter stopService
    startService.mustRunAfter doUpdateB
    doUpdateA.mustRunAfter stopService
    startService.mustRunAfter doUpdateA
}
```

with up-to-date checks moved to doUpdateX works, but again is suboptimal for reasons this margin is too short to contain.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,

Comment: Any update on this question?